# Programmatically get amount of facebook likes for a specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I'm building a website in ASP.net/C# and currently I want to get the amount of Facebook likes of a specific page (think of a video/article). I need this value programmatically, because I want to sort on it later, but that's a different story.

I already know the link Facebook itself provides to get this amount, which is posted below.

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27

With www.google.com being the website, whose links are being counted and can of course be changed to whichever page one needs.

Does anybody know how I can access the xml file, of the URL/XML file posted above? I've done some research, but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me.

EDIT: I found the answer. I had to navigate through the XML a bit and modify the actual URL used. Working code is posted below.

```
string result;
        string urlToXMLfile, currentURL;
        currentURL = Globals.NavigateURL(TabId, "", "CategoryId=" + catId, "MovieId=" + Request.QueryString["MovieId"]);

        urlToXMLfile = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22";
        urlToXMLfile += currentURL;
        urlToXMLfile += "%22";

        //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(urlToXMLfile);
        //string test = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("like_count")).First().Value;


        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(urlToXMLfile);

        result = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.InnerText;

        return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added my own answer below the question. That line of code works and returns a simple String, with the amount of FB likes that page got.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue once, when I've worked with Selenium. I found that for me it was ok just to get the text representation of that xml and keep it simple string, storing the HTML body in a variable. Which allowed me later to extract the count I need via regex or other algorithm.

Comment: ah interesting. I've also considered to get it as a String and convert it to an int later on. Do you have any idea how you did it at the time? Some code perhaps?

Comment: Sadly I've used it in previous project. But I'll try to find this solution and provide code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/GetPageSource.html) solution for you, try this:

`string pageSource = driver.getPageSource();`

and after you get the data, you can do something like:

`// Extract the text between the two like_count elements
  pattern = "(?i)(<like_count.*?>)(.+?)(</like_count>)";`

Comment: what is driver?

Comment: @Ateeq I've updated the answer, so now it is clear that Selenium is used to scrape the web page.